# Count unseen messages from object Lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I am trying to get count of unseen messages from object in lodash.

below is my object

```
[
  "conversation_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e484"
  "messages": [
            {
                "message_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e483",
                "sender_uid": 2,
                "receiver_uid": 1,
                "created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z",
                "status": 1,
                "delivered": false,
                "seen": true,
            }
     ]

]
```

I want to get count of `seen: false` messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to get all `see = false` messages and then can check length

```js
var users = {
"conversation_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e484",
"messages": [
    { "message_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e483","sender_uid": 2,"receiver_uid": 1,"created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z","status": 1,"delivered": false,"seen": true,},
    { "message_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e483","sender_uid": 2,"receiver_uid": 1,"created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z","status": 1,"delivered": false,"seen": false },
    { "message_id": "5b88779b2321141f2864e483","sender_uid": 2, "receiver_uid": 1, "created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z", "status": 1,"delivered": false,"seen": false,}
]
}


var unseen_messages = _.filter(users.messages, message => { return !message.seen; }).length;
console.log(unseen_messages);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Without lodash you can use `reduce`

```js
var users = {
    "conversation_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e484",
    "messages": [
        { "message_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e483","sender_uid": 2,"receiver_uid": 1,"created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z","status": 1,"delivered": false,"seen": true,},
        { "message_id": "5a88779b2321141f2864e483","sender_uid": 2,"receiver_uid": 1,"created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z","status": 1,"delivered": false,"seen": false },
        { "message_id": "5b88779b2321141f2864e483","sender_uid": 2, "receiver_uid": 1, "created": "2018-02-17T18:42:35.252Z", "status": 1,"delivered": false,"seen": false,}
    ]
}

items = users.messages;
var totalCount = items.reduce((total, obj) => { return (!obj.seen) ? (total +1) : total }, 0);
console.log(totalCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

_.sumBy would do the trick

```
const unseenMessages = _.sumBy(users.messages, message => message.seen === false);
```